# How to extract list from google endpoint class to my activity?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

Endpoint class method:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "listRecords")
public List<ReplyRecord> listRecords(@Named("count") int count) {
    List<ReplyRecord> records = ofy().load().type(ReplyRecord.class).limit(count).list();
    return records;
}
```

activity method call inside AsyncTask doInBackground

```
regService.record(sf.getString("regId","0"),obj.getqId(),obj.getAnsId()).execute();
        Registration.ListRecords rr= regService.listRecords(20);
```

this is not a direct call to api method so I get some **Registration.ListRecords** type object. Iam really confused please suggest me the way to get **List**  type directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  The `ListRecords` object in the model is basically a request, so you also have to execute it and call `.getItems()` to get the resultant `List` when done:

```
List<ReplyRecord> results = rr.execute().getItems();
```